# Split the Array column in pyspark dataframe

Tags: arrays, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, split

I have a data frame like below

```
 col1
 -----------------
 [a1_b1_c1, a2_b2_c2, a3_b3_c3]
 [aa1_bb1_cc1, aa2_bb2_cc2, aa3_bb3]
 [aaa2_bbb2_ccc1, aaa2_bbb2_cc2, aaa3_bbb3]
```

now I want to split the elements, need to form the below-mentioned data frame,

```
newcol1
--------
[c1,c2,c3]
[cc1,cc2,null]
[ccc1,ccc2,null]
```

Please suggest to me the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Which version of Spark are you on?

Comment: spark 2.4.4  and  python3

Comment: @Yeskay Glad you found my solution helpful! Please consider also upvoting it, in addition to already having accepted it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your desired output by using a [`udf`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html)

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

def my_split(l):
  ll = [e.split('_') + [None]*(3 - len(e.split('_'))) for e in l]
  return [e[2] for e in ll]

my_udf = F.udf(my_split, T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))

df = df.withColumn('newcol1', my_udf('col1'))

df.show(truncate=False)

+------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|col1                                      |newcol1          |
+------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|[a1_b1_c1, a2_b2_c2, a3_b3_c3]            |[c1, c2, c3]     |
|[aa1_bb1_cc1, aa2_bb2_cc2, aa3_bb3]       |[cc1, cc2, null] |
|[aaa2_bbb2_ccc1, aaa2_bbb2_cc2, aaa3_bbb3]|[ccc1, cc2, null]|
+------------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [built-in higher order function](https://databricks.com/blog/2018/11/16/introducing-new-built-in-functions-and-higher-order-functions-for-complex-data-types-in-apache-spark.html) called as TRANSFORM.

```
df.createTempView("tab")
spark.sql(
"select col1, TRANSFORM(col1, v-> split(v, '_')[2]) as newcol1 from tab")\
.show(truncate=False)

+------------------------------------------+------------+
|col1                                      |newcol1     |
+------------------------------------------+------------+
|[a1_b1_c1, a2_b2_c2, a3_b3_c3]            |[c1, c2, c3]|
|[aa1_bb1_cc1, aa2_bb2_cc2, aa3_bb3]       |[cc1, cc2,] |
|[aaa2_bbb2_ccc1, aaa2_bbb2_cc2, aaa3_bbb3]|[ccc1, cc2,]|
+------------------------------------------+------------+
```